# 'pyrcc4' is not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: python, osgeo4w

```
C:\Users\Department\.qgis2\python\plugins\np>pyrcc4 -py2 resources.qrc -o resources.py
```

> 'pyrcc4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you use the OSGeo4W Shell for the command? The Windows commander doesn't work in this way. QGIS 2.18.x: The `pyrcc4.exe` is found in `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use OSGEO Shell to run this command.

Go to Start Menu and search for OSGEO Shell, and then command prompt window will be open.

Now type `cd C:\Users\Department.qgis2\python\plugins\np>` in the shell, and press enter.

It will set the current directory to the plugin directory.

Now run your pyrcc4 command.

You can also follow detailed tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@ahsanmukhtar02/qgis-plugin-development-installation-and-configuration-on-windows-d70eab25e2f1)

Answer (score -1):

for me adding the pyrcc4 path to system environment variables made it work
`C:\Users\BenBouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4`

Comment: In your path, we can read `Python35` and `PyQt4`. This won't work with QGIS. QGIS 3 uses Qt5/PyQt5 and Python 3. QGIS 2 uses Qt4/PyQt4 and Python 2. So there is an incompatibility. You must switch to `pyrcc5` with QGIS 3

Comment: i needed pyrcc4 for compatibility with a few things, i don't need pyrcc all that much i'm just showing people a possible path to the executable, maybe it'd help someone?