# pyrcc4 command not recognized as internal or external command?

Tags: python, qgis-plugins

The question has already been asked as ['pyrcc4' is not recognized as an internal or external command?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/295811/115) but the answers did not fit my own trouble.

I am trying to create a plug-in. I followed the Qgis Cookbook and when I start the OSGeoW4 shell I type the following code (xxx is the name of the Beta plugin) :

```
cd c:\Users\Guillaume\.qgis2\python\plugins\xxx
```

then 
     make

which doesn't work nor

```
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

They are not recognized as internal or external command.

So little research lead me to look after the /bin from qgis and I found pyrcc4.exe but no pyrcc4.bat

I have two python version (2.7) one from the ArcGIS package which is working nicely as a shell on pyzo python interpreter, and one downloaded from the python.org.

I'm working with QGIS 2.18.23

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from the computer specialist of my university. As the pyrcc4 command is searching the .exe in python files (path defined in the environnement variable from the system) we had to allow the computer to search further since it is in the QGIS 2.18 file. 
    `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\o4w_env.bat"`
The code call and set path to QGIS \bin file.

Comment: In order to ensure discoverability of good answers, we aim not to duplicate questions. Please add your alternative answer to the older question.